# Is using a $\Rightarrow$ to separate simplification steps valid?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Say I have function $y -2 = -4(x + 1)$. Is it a valid use of $\Rightarrow$ to, in the course of simplification, do this:

$y -2 = -4(x + 1) \Rightarrow y = -4x -2$?

Both sides of the equation are equal, and from what I understand of that symbol this is appropriate, but I'm not sure.

For all of high school I did something similar to this, except I just used $\rightarrow$ between the steps, especially in Algebra, to keep the actual simplifications separate, and never had any issues with any teachers doing this. I felt it kept my work cleaner, but my Calc professor marks us down for doing that, and I'd prefer to be able to separate steps out a bit more than

$y -2 = -4(x + 1) = y = -4x -2$

Comment: I'm also not sure what exactly to tag this with, it's my first time posting on Mathematics and none of the tags that really applied that I could think of existed.

Comment: Note that in a chain of equals signs $a=b=c$ implies that $a=b$ that $b=c$ and by transitivity of the equals sign that $a=c$ as well.  Your final line that you wrote reads "$y-2=-4(x+1)=y=-4x-2$" and would have implied that $y-2=y$ which would imply that $0=2$ which is not true if we were talking about real numbers.  Use equals signs **only for equality** and not for "continuing to next step" markers.  Use extended blank space, or arrows, or something else other than an equals sign for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the question is. In logic, the $\implies$ symbol means "implies." So it is certainly true that $y-2=x\implies y=x+2$, for example. In your second example, it makes no sense to write

$$y -2 = -4(x + 1) = y = -4x -2$$

since you have just written $y-2=y$ and thus $-2=0$.

I'm not sure why any instructor would mark down for using $\implies$, unless she specifically asked you to use english words. Maybe you should check in with them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should work fine: the $\Rightarrow$ means logical implication, and the statement $y-2=-4(x+1)$ does indeed logically imply that $y=-4x-2$

What you do at the end, though:

> $y-2=-4(x+1)=y=-4x-2$

is certainly *not* correct, because you end up saying that $y-2=y$

Comment: Maybe $-2 = 0$?